# Preview new website without editing vhosts on customers device

Tags: networking, cpanel, preview, vhosts

I have an existing website on domain e.g.: '123.com' hosted in company A.

On the other hand I have my server in company B, created the account for '123.com' and a new wordpress site.

I can preview the new website by editing vhosts file on mac-OS, but if I want the client to preview the new site on the same domain?

I tried once with one client to edit vhosts file but was imposible, as he had no knowledge about vhosts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using cPanel you can do it via IP/~username;

Ex: http://255.255.255.255/~username

Replace "255.255.255.255" with the IP of your server and "username" with the username of your account.

Also, you can do it by creating a subdomain. More about this one you can find here: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9178/32/how-can-i-check-the-content-of-my-website-before-switching-the-dns-records